# How to append string to each json keys while selecting json keys using jsonb_object_keys or json_object_keys in postgres?

Tags: json, postgresql

I have table called `data_table`

```
CREATE TABLE data_table(d_id int, d_json jsonb, c_id int, t_id int);
```

And json data in table like:

```
INSERT INTO data_table
VALUES (1,'{
    "key11": "value11",
    "key21": "value21",
    "key31": "value31",
    "key41": "value41",
    "key51": "value51",
    "key61": "value61"
}',1,1);
```

Now I want output as

[image: expected output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `CONCAT_WS` in Select Query.

`CONCAT_WS` is a `Postgres` function that stands for "Concatenate With Separator". It takes multiple strings as input and concatenates them into a single string using a specified separator between each string. The first argument of the function is the separator, followed by the strings to be concatenated.

Here is code:

```
 SELECT 
  CONCAT_WS('', STRING_AGG(DISTINCT CONCAT(json_keys.json_column_key, e' TEXT'), e',\n\t'), '') AS json_column_list 
 FROM 
  (SELECT jsonb_object_keys(d_json) AS json_column_key FROM data_table) AS json_keys
```